# python recursive regular expression

Tags: python, regex, recursion

I have a message that is

```
msg = 'untagged ethernet 1 ethernet 2 ethernet 3'
```

and I want to write a regex that will find the 'ethernet x' pattern so that if i run

```
m = re.match(str(regex),msg) 
print m.groups()
```

it will save the variable x and display something like

```
(1,2,3)
```

the expression that I have tried is

```
regex = 'untagged ((?: ethernet (\S+))*)'
```

but i am getting

```
('ethernet 1', 'ethernet 1', '1')\
```

as a result

Answer (score 4):

You should use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) instead of `re.match`:

```
>>> import re
>>> msg = 'untagged ethernet 1 ethernet 2 ethernet 3'
>>> re.findall("ethernet\s\d+", msg)
['ethernet 1', 'ethernet 2', 'ethernet 3']
>>> re.findall("ethernet\s(\d+)", msg)  # Just the numbers
['1', '2', '3']
>>> tuple(map(int, re.findall("ethernet\s(\d+)", msg)))  # What was in your post
(1, 2, 3)
>>>
```

`re.findall` was designed explicitly for finding all occurrences of a pattern inside a string.